# Why is the hydrolysis of the conjugate base of a weak acid neglected in buffer solutions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, hydrolysis

Consider a solution which contains a weak acid and the salt of its conjugate base with a strong base. 
e.g. $$\ce{CH3COOH + H2O <=>[$K_\rm{a}$] CH3COO- + H3O+}\tag1$$
$$\ce{CH3COO- + H2O <=>[$K_\rm{h}$] CH3COOH + OH-}\tag2$$

Now, $\displaystyle{K_\rm{a} = \frac{[\ce{H3O+}] [\ce{CH3COO-}]}{[\ce{CH3COOH}]}}$ and $\displaystyle{K_\mathrm{h} = \frac{K_\rm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a}}}$.

Now, my notes say that for the equilibrium concentration of undissociated acid, the acid coming due to hydrolysis of the salt is neglected and the equilibrium concentration is approximately equal to the initial concentration.

It is also mentioned in a book that

> Assume that the extent of protonation of acetate ions and
>   the deprotonation of acetic acid molecules is so small that the concentrations of both
>   species are nearly the same as their initial values.

Why is this so? If $K_\rm{a}$ is low, then $K_\rm{h}$ should be high. I understand that the deprotonation of acid will be low as it is a weak acid so that we can neglect the $\ce{CH3COO-}$ coming through the acid dissociation but **how can we neglect the hydrolysis of the $\ce{CH3COO-}$ coming from the salt?**

Edit $-$

My calculation for equilibrium concentrations.

$\ce{[CH3COOH]_\mathrm{eq}} =$ initially added acid $-$ deprotonated acid $+$ hydrolysed salt

$\ce{[CH3COO-]_\mathrm{eq}} =$ initially added salt $-$ hydrolysed salt $+$ deprotonated acid

$\ce{[H3O+]}_{\mathrm{eq}} =$ deprotonated acid $-$ hydrolysed salt

Let the concentration of

initially added acid $= c_1$

initially added salt $= c_2$

deprotonated acid at eq. $= x$

hydrolysed salt at eq. $= y$

Thus, $$K_{\mathrm{a}}  = \frac{[\ce{H3O+}] [\ce{CH3COO-}]}{[\ce{CH3COOH}]} = \frac{(x - y)(c_2 - y + x)}{(c_1 - x + y)}$$

Now, assuming $x << c_1, \, c_2$,

$$K_{\mathrm{a}}  = \frac{(- y)(c_2 - y)}{(c_1 + y)}$$

Comment: You may take it into account and compare the results.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Please see my edited question.

Comment: You said before that you neglect $y$, not $x$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I said that I understand why deprotonation is neglected, i.e. why $x$ is neglected. I don't understand why the hydrolysis, i.e. $y$ is neglected.

Comment: Hydrolysis = cleavage of chem. bonds by addition of water (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolysis). Where is there a hydrolysis here? How can acetic acid be hydrolyzed?

Comment: @deusexmachina From the link you've provided, see [Salts subsection on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolysis#Salts)

Comment: @deusexmachina It states that "A common kind of hydrolysis occurs when a salt of a weak acid or weak base (or both) is dissolved in water. Water spontaneously ionizes into hydroxide anions and hydronium cations. The salt also dissociates into its constituent anions and cations. For example, **sodium acetate dissociates in water into sodium and acetate ions. Sodium ions react very little with the hydroxide ions whereas the acetate ions combine with hydronium ions to produce acetic acid. In this case the net result is a relative excess of hydroxide ions, yielding a basic solution.**"

Comment: @deusexmachina The salt $\ce{CH3COONa}$ does hydrolyse as shown in the reaction numbered $(2)$ in my question.

Comment: @downvoter Why the downvote? Am I unclear in my question?

Comment: So your question is why the acidity of a weak acid cannot be neglected? Why don't you just give some numbers, including all concentrations. Then you can just calculate it out.

Comment: @deusexmachina I'm somewhat confused about the meaning of the word 'acidity'. My question is "Why do we neglect the protonation of acetate ions(of the acetate ions coming through the salt)?"

Comment: Of course you cannot neglect the concentration of $\mathsf{CH3COO^-}$. And assuming $\mathsf{CH3COONa}$ to be completely dissociated should be a good approximation. So obviously, you may not neglect the concentration of the sodium acetate. Basically if you double the concentration of the sodium acetate, the concentration of the hydronium ions will go down to keep equilibrium.

Comment: @deusexmachina I'm talking about the neglection of the $\ce{CH3COOH}$ which is coming through the protonation of the acetate ion.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 4.75$, therefore $K_\mathrm{a} = 10^{-4.75}$. Thus,

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{[\ce{AcO^-}][\ce{H+}]}{[\ce{AcOH}]}$$

So, let's assume $[\ce{AcOH}] = \pu{1.0 M}$. Just to get a feel, how far the acid is dissociated:

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{x \cdot x}{\pu{1.0 M}} \to x = \sqrt{10^{-4.75}}~\pu{M} = 0.00422 \approx 0.4\%$$

where we have assumed that the contribution from the dissociation of water is negligible, and therefore $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{AcO-}] = x$.

Now, what happens if I add $\pu{1.0 M}$ $\ce{AcO-}$? Then, effectively, we have:

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{[\ce{AcO-}][\ce{H+}]}{[\ce{AcOH}]} = \frac{\pu{1.0 M}
 \cdot [\ce{H+}]}{\pu{1.0 M}}$$

Therefore, we have:

$$[\ce{H+}] = K_\mathrm{a} \frac{\pu{1.0 M}}{\pu{1.0 M}} = \pu{10^{-4.75} M}$$

If we compare the two cases, before addition of acetate, we had a $\mathrm{pH}$ of

$$[\ce{H+}] = \sqrt{10^{-4.75}} \to \mathrm{pH} = 2.375$$

and after addition of acetate, we have

$$[\ce{H+}] = 10^{-4.75} \to \mathrm{pH} = 4.75$$

Meaning that the solution got more basic after the addition of acetate, as excpected.

Comment: Hopefully that provides a good starting point for understanding.

Comment: @deuxexmachina After you added 1.0 M acetate ions, how did you take equilibrium concentration to be 1.0 M? How is initial concentration equal to equilibrium concentration?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Yeah, I figured that this point wasn't really clear yet. So first of all, you can neglect that the acid CH3COOH will dissociate to CH3COO-, as by the above argument, it only dissociates to a very little extent. However, your concern is the other way around, and you argue that CH3COO-Na+ could be protonated to form CH3COOH + NaOH. But: look at the pKa of NaOH and CH3OO-Na: NaOH is a much stronger base! Therefore, you can assume that $\mathrm{[NaCH3COO] = [NaCH3COO]_0}$.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis You can also find a similar description here:  http://study.com/academy/lesson/acid-base-buffers-calculating-the-ph-of-a-buffered-solution.html for a similar explanation

Comment: Can you add your comment about $\ce{NaOH}$ being a stronger base into the answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: Also, can you show in your answer that without taking $y$ into consideration, $y$ comes out equal to $K_\rm{a} = 1.8 \times 10^{-5}$. Taking $y$ into conideration will not change its value very much. So, we can say that $y << c_1, c_2.$